# Data-bound WinForms form - how to format dates?

Tags: winforms, data-binding, datetime, compact-framework, formatting

I have a form with a date value in a TextBox control. The form uses data binding with a BindingSource against a DataSet and a SQL 2005 CE database.
Where do I control the formatting of the date? Nowhere in the properties along the way did I see a possibility to strip out the time part, for instance.

I could of course do it in the database and pass a string instead of a DateTime, but that's workaround and not a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the designer, select your textbox, click on the properties tab, choose (DataBindings) - Advanced.

In here you can select the Date Time datatype and optionally strip out just the date or the time etc.

Comment: Wow, how did I not see that ... ?

Answer (score 7):

You can handle the event **Binding.Format** event to format the date.  And its counterpart **Binding.Parse** to parse the input from the TextBox.

E.g.

```
TextBox.DataBindings["Text"].Format += new ConvertEventHandler(FormatDateEventHandler);
...
private void FormatDateEventHandler (object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
    if (! Convert.IsDBNull (e.Value))
    {
        e.Value = ((DateTime)e.Value).ToString ("d", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
}
```